# Vue.js unable to get the value of jQuery select2

Tags: jquery, vue.js, jquery-select2

I'm here with a problem.  am using vue.js as cdn. So not like I can install npm and use packages.

The problem starts when I try to use jQuery's select2 plugin. It shows the option values correctly which are coming dynamically, but the problem occurs when I select a value, vue.js doesn't actually get that. Just to inform you that it works perfectly and vue does get the value if I don't use select2 class.

Here is my select option part of the code

```
<select v-model="formData.allowance_id" id="allowance_id"
        name="allowance_id" class="form-control select2" required>
     <option :key="'allowance_id'" value="">choose allowance</option>
     <option v-for="(allowance, index) in allowances" :key="'allowance_id' + index" :value="allowance.id">
     @{{ allowance.name }}
     </option>
</select>
```

here is my vue part

```
new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            allowances: '',
            formData: {
                allowance_id: ''
            },
    mounted: function () {
           this.getallowances()
    }
})
```

and here is the  jQuery's part

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
     $.('.select2').select2();
})
</script>
```

I have tried loading the select2 before/after the vue.js, also tried calling it in mounted, but nothing worked. please help me - I'm stuck

Answer (score 3):

I don't encourage mixing jQuery and Vue. For example in the snippet below which uses the jQuery select2 plugin you mentioned, once you do `$('.select2').select2()` then the `v-model="formData.allowance_id"` is useless because select2 does its own thing.

If you want to continue down this route and you're submitting a form with ajax, you could get the value when you submit the form.

Concerning your Vue, [data must be a function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function) and `mounted` isn't part of `data`.

EDIT:

After looking at the [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/vuejs/vuejs.org/tree/master/src/v2/examples/vue-20-wrapper-component?from-embed) for the [Select2 - Wrapper component example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html) that @Julia provided, there's a change event you can subscribe to with select2, that you could use to update your model, something like this: `.on("change", function() { self.onSelectChange(this.value); });`

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => {
    return {
      allowances: [],
      formData: {
        allowance_id: null
      }
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getallowances();
    
    let self = this;
    $('.select2').select2().on("change", function() {
      self.onSelectChange(this.value);
    });
  },
  methods: {
    onSelectChange(val) {
      this.formData.allowance_id = val;
    },
    onSubmit() {
      this.formData.allowance_id = $($(".select2")[0]).val();
    },
    getallowances() {
      this.allowances = [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Test"
      }];
    }

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select v-model="formData.allowance_id" id="allowance_id" name="allowance_id" class="form-control select2" required @input="alert('Test')">
    <option :key="'allowance_id'" value="">choose allowance</option>
    <option v-for="(allowance, index) in allowances" :key="allowance.id" :value="allowance.id">
      @{{ allowance.name }}
    </option>
  </select>

  <div>
    <strong>Selected: </strong> {{formData.allowance_id}}
  </div>

  <div>
    <button type="button" @click="onSubmit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: one more favor i would ask for, if i want to perform an ajax operation on changing the option, as vue cant detect it, what can i do to call a function in vue.?

Comment: @AbidusSattarAziz I've updated my answer with a method `onSelectChange` that gets called when the select value changes.

Answer (score 0):

select2 hides the select and does its own thing, if you inspect the code, you'll notice it. That's why you cannot listen to the event on the select.

There's an example of mixing a jQuery plugin and VueJS in the official doc [Select2 - Wrapper component example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html)

Comment: i have already tried this..works fine, but if i use any other html's out of component they dont show up